# C# : Method having IEnumerable<Type> as argument. What is a valid input?

Tags: c#, types, ienumerable

I am trying to define a valid input  for my method Pairwise. Pairwise takes an argument IEnumerable which I am having trouble figuring out what is exactly. I have tried alot of stuff but can never really get there.

```
public delegate void PairwiseDel(Type left, Type right);

public static void Pairwise(IEnumerable<Type> col, PairwiseDel del)
{
   // stuff happens here which passes pairs from col to del
}
```

can someone plz tell and illustrate what a valid input for my method would be?

Comment: And yes this is a school assignment but you are not making my homework. Far from it. This is a tiny step at which i am stuck atm.

Comment: You can pass object of any class which implements IEnumerable <T> such as List <T>. Better you read first about Object Oriented Programming Concepts, Interface and Generics.

Comment: Type is a class defined in FCL so IEnumerable<Type> myTypes = new List<Type>(); can be passed as valid parameter. Dont understand what you are trying to acheve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a valid input:

```
var collection = new List<Type>();
collection.Add(typeof(string));
collection.Add(typeof(int));

PairWise(collection, YourDelegateHere);
```

Comment: I get it now. <Type> literally means the string, int, long, etc keywords. I thought it was an abstract thing for me to be able to pass almost anything

Answer (score 1):

[`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is a very important interface in .NET library. It represents an abstraction describing a sequence of elements of type `T`.

This generic interface has multiple implementations:

- Built-in 1-dimension arrays `T[]` implement `IEnumerable<T>`
- All generic .NET collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`
- Methods that use `yield return` produce `IEnumerable<T>`
- Multiple methods in .NET LINQ library both take and return `IEnumerable<T>`

If you would like to test your method, pass it an array `Type[]`:

```
var items = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(long) };
Pairwise(items, (a, b) => {
    Console.WriteLine("A={0}, B={1}", a.Name, b.Name);
});
```

Comment: so you are saying var items = new Type[]{1,2,3,4,5}; would be valid input? That errors on my end. Saying enable to convert int to System.Type

Comment: @Nulle I never said you could initialize an array of elements of type `Type` with integers. You need to specify types there.